# TypeError: unbound method set.intersection() needs an argument

Tags: python, set

Consider this snippet, which is working fine:

```py
import numpy as np

MC = 100_000
N, P = 107, 14
rpp = 15  # Roles per person
R = 2     # The correct role
boxes = np.arange(N)


len_interstct_1try = []
#  for _ in range(MC):
split_roles = [set(np.random.choice(boxes, size=rpp, replace=False)) for _ in range(P)]
intrsctn = set.intersection(*[r for r in split_roles if R in r])
len_interstct_1try.append(len(intrsctn))
```

How is it possible that the following instead

```py
len_interstct_1try = []
for _ in range(MC):
    split_roles = [set(np.random.choice(boxes, size=rpp, replace=False)) for _ in range(P)]
    intrsctn = set.intersection(*[r for r in split_roles if R in r])
    len_interstct_1try.append(len(intrsctn))
```

raises the following error? I am quite confused...

```
  File "<ipython-input-46-49ef6704b64c>", line 4, in <module>
    intrsctn = set.intersection(*[r for r in split_roles if R in r])
TypeError: unbound method set.intersection() needs an argument
```

Comment: Why do you think `[r for r in split_roles if R in r]` isn't empty?

Comment: Can you also explain the rationale of your code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: ah, thanks. if it's empty the intersection has no attributes...got it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in your code, `[r for r in split_roles if R in r]` returns an empty list.

Thus expansion with `*` will fail to pass parameters to `set.intersection`:

```
set.intersection(*[r for r in split_roles if R in r])
```

You might want to use a test:

```
for _ in range(MC):
    split_roles = [set(np.random.choice(boxes, size=rpp, replace=False)) for _ in range(P)]
    l = [r for r in split_roles if R in r]
    if l:
        intrsctn = set.intersection(*l)
        len_interstct_1try.append(len(intrsctn))
```

Or a `try`/`except` to stop the loop (or maybe add `0`?):

```
len_interstct_1try = []
for _ in range(MC):
    split_roles = [set(np.random.choice(boxes, size=rpp, replace=False)) for _ in range(P)]
    try:
        intrsctn = set.intersection(*[r for r in split_roles if R in r])
    except TypeError:
        break
    len_interstct_1try.append(len(intrsctn))
```

Comment: Yes, try / except is what I had done, but it's not as clean. The above seems better thanks!

Comment: `try`/`except` is pythonic, and not expensive if you use it to break. Don't hesitate to use it ;)